# После использования sql бекапа сбросилась последовательность ключей

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Недавно была ситуация, нам потребовалось создать бекап базы данных, и через день загрузить его обратно на чистую базу. Однако через время мы заметили как сайт начал выходить из строя, оказалось что новые записи пытались вставь на место новых. **База postgresql**

Было найдено одно глупое, но рабочее решение - отослать запрос пустышку, так как после неудачной попытки, ключ все равно увеличивался, и таким образом, я дошел в одной базе до 4,000 ключа.
Однако уже понятно, что это не одна база, и в других по 100,000+ записей.

Суть в том, что нужно каким то образом сместить последовательность ключей, но я нигде не нашел как это можно сделать. Сойдет как метод решения, так и уловки.

Comment: *последовательность ключей* Чем именно генерятся ключи? если это sequence, так есть [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html)...

Comment: @Akina Ключи генерируются через auto increment с 0, если я вас неправильно понял, дайте мне знать

Comment: *Ключи генерируются через auto increment с 0* Покажите это в виде SQL-кода, не надо на пальцах. Постгресс вообще не знает auto increment - у него либо sequence, либо identity. Ну или SERIAL как алиас.

Comment: Напишите как именно вы делали бекап и как потом восстанавливали. Потому что соответствующие вызовы setval в pg_dump/pg_restore предусмотрены.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас узнаем, это может занять время, так как это произошло в неловких обстоятельствах.

Comment: Я не очень разбираюсь в данной базе данных, так как раньше с ней не работал, поэтому извиняйте если туплю.
Возможно, это даст ответ, по умолчанию в ключе стоит `nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)`